# Chrome Maximise with Protractor and VSTS Pipelines (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, protractor

We've recently moved to VSTS from TeamCity and on the whole it's been a positive experience. However, there's one issue that's causing me grief.

I need to run our Jasmine/Protractor tests with Chrome maximised (some modal pop-ups cannot be 'seen' if not maximised.

When run on my local machine in VS Code there are no issues however, when run on VSTS Agents,

```
 capabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
  args: [ 
    '--start-maximised'
      ]
    }
},
```

....has no effect.

```
 capabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
  args: ['--window-size=1920,1080']
}
    },
```

...also had no effect.

```
onPrepare: function() {
  var width = 1600;
  var height = 1200;
  browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
},
```

...generates...

```
E/launcher - unknown error: cannot get automation extension
```

Anyone got any other suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is with the chrome version you are using. Try updating the chrome to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @SudharsanSelvaraj. Where should Chrome be updated to the latest version? On the VSTS agent?